# get JSON Path from Java Object

Tags: java, json, rest

How do i get jsonpointer path for particular field?
For example

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "code": 101,
    "details": {
        "education": "UG",
        "age": 0
    }
}
```

if any one of the field have some validation issue, we need to send error in json pointer notation **"field":"/details/age"** invalid details.

Sample Error Message

```
{
    "errors": [
       {
         "name": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
         "details": [
           {
             "field":"/details/age",
             "value": "",
             "issue": "Invalid Param::age",
             "location": "body"
           }
         ],
         "message": "Invalid data provided"
       }
     ]
 }
```

While validating request object how do i get the field path in JSONPointer notation like above. We send the json request then it mapped below object.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "name", "code", "details" })
public class Example {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("code")
    private Integer code;
    @JsonProperty("details")
    private Details details;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("code")
    public Integer getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @JsonProperty("code")
    public void setCode(Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @JsonProperty("details")
    public Details getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    @JsonProperty("details")
    public void setDetails(Details details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

}


public class Details {

    @JsonProperty("education")
    private String education;
    @JsonProperty("age")
    private Integer age;

    @JsonProperty("education")
    public String getEducation() {
        return education;
    }

    @JsonProperty("education")
    public void setEducation(String education) {
        this.education = education;
    }

    @JsonProperty("age")
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @JsonProperty("age")
    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you validating?

Comment: @shmosel In our REST service we are validating, 

the process is when we receive json request to our Rest service, it mapped to the request object, then we validating the particular object.